# undefined CryptoJS in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cryptojs

https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

i have install cryptoJs using npm i crypto-js

but how do i use it on my project ?
when i write this code

```html
// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');

var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(originalText);
```

but it show an error said that CryptoJS is undefined

here is my code

```html
<script>
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'
require('crypto-js')

export default {
  name: "AnswerQuestionnaire",
  components:{
  
  },
  props: {
  
  },
  data() {
    return {
     
    }
  },

  created(){
    this.CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("zU5jEPwQSm2P0X33jgH6sg==", "sB7b5q4fp0G59R9t").toString(this.CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
      
  },
  mounted(){
    
  }
};
```

this is the eror

```html
VM820424:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CryptoJs is not defined
    at eval (eval at created
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/tpenaranda/vue-cryptojs ?

Comment: You should use only require or import, not both. Do not use `this.CryptoJS.AES`, use only `CryptoJS.AES`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you have to run `npm install crypto-js` in Vue terminal.

Then, you have to import or require crypto first

```html
<script>
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
export default {
  created() {
    var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');

    var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    console.log(originalText); 
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'
require('crypto-js')

i have add that and still CryptoJS still undefined

Comment: Okey, could you update your question with more code?

Comment: i have put my code to my question , did you see something wrong sir ?